# declare variable if variable declared already

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to do something like this:

```
{% if user.get_profile.gender == 'F' %}
   var gender = her
{% endif %} 

{% if user.get_profile.gender == 'M' %}
    var gender = him
{% endif %}
```

And later in the template say something like:

```
<a href=#>Message {{gender}}</a>
```

And what if the `user.get_profile.gender` is empty? how can i check for that too?

Sorry, I'm new the django and python in general....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (easily) do that with django's template language. This is by design. The [documentation mentions this specifically](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/):

> the template system is meant to express presentation, not program logic.

Instead, it would be much easier to write a simple method on your profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...

    def pronoun(self):
        if self.gender == 'F':
            return "her"
        elif self.gender == 'M':
            return "him"
        return "them"
```

and call that instead:

```
{{ user.get_profile.pronoun }}
```

An alternative to this would be to [write a template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) that you could use on the attribute that would take the value of the `gender` field and return the appropriate string. This would be useful if you were planning to reuse the function

```
@register.filter(name='gender_pronoun')
def gender_pronoun(value):
    if self.gender == 'F':
        return "her"
    elif self.gender == 'M':
        return "him"
    return "them"
```

and call it like so in the template

```
{{ user.get_profile.gender|gender_pronoun }}
```

Comment: Nooooooooo!!!! oh well.... - your answer works, thx for the help! - "gosh i miss `php`"

Comment: Don't worry, with some practice you will come around to this way of thinking.